# change content src value dynamically in config.xml in cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova

Is there any way that I can change `src` value of the content tag present inside `config.xml`.

My config file look like this.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloCordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="browser" spec="^5.0.4" />
    <engine name="android" spec="^7.1.4" />
</widget>
```

I want that `src` property something like

`<content src="'${cordova.app.url}'/index.html">`

and the `cordova.app.url` I want to declare in a file named `application.properties` somehow like we see in Spring Hibernate projects.

**application.properties**

```
cordova.app.url=http://f9/
cordova.app.name=HelloWorld
...
```

So I want a file in my cordova project where I can declare properties with values and use it in `config.xml` or other files. Is it possible?

Comment: Not that I know of. Why not just load index.html and have your JS figure out what it needs to load?

Comment: Hello from 2022. Any luck on that matter?

Comment: No luck @nyan-cat, we cannot change it dynamically.